# Magento 2.1 issue product attributes not loading saved data

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I created an issue for this in github, because i assumed this was a bug in the newest version of magento.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5445

The selected value is saved the first time in the db table catalog_product_entity_varchar, and the attribute is added to the eav_attribute table, but when i load the edit product view the data does not load, i.e. the selected options are not highlighted against the attribute.
[image]

Attribute installation is as follows 
$this->addMultiSelectFieldWithSource($eavSetup, 'special_requirements', 'Special requirements', false, 4,

```
'Amrita\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\SpecialRequirements');   

 private function addMultiSelectFieldWithSource($eavSetup, $fieldName, $fieldTitle, $required, $position, $source) {
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Product::ENTITY,
        $fieldName,
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => $fieldTitle,
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'required' => $required,
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'source' => $source,
            'global' => Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'system' => 0,
            'searchable' => true,
            'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'filterable_in_search' => true,
            'position' => $position,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'group' => 'General',
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
        ]
    );
```

And the source for the attribute is as follows

```
    <?php

namespace Amrita\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class SpecialRequirements extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 1,               'label' => 'Suitable for Vegetarians'],
            ['value' => 2,  'label' => 'Suitable for Pregnancy or Breastfeeding'],
            ['value' => 3,                    'label' => 'Suitable for Vegans'],
            ['value' => 4,                 'label' => 'Suitable for Children']
        ];
    }
}
```

Is this to do with the upgrade? Or is this an issue with the installation of the attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Can you find any solution? if yes than post it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this can be fixed by having string values instead of integers in the source. So ['value' => 1, ...] becomes ['value' => '1'].

I'm uncertain why this is the case but it seems to have something to do with the way KnockoutJS works out which values to select.